What are some good resources for learning Detection and Estimation theory?
I know about Vincent Poor's book but it is not the best of books to be honest. Are there other good resources such as online lectures or other books/notes that one might find useful? I mainly need help with the Detection part as I am already quite familiar with Estimation theory.

Melsa and Cohn: Decision and Estimation Theory.  It might be a good thing to learn probability, random variables, and random processes first.  Really get Bayesian Inference down pat.

Kay's Volume I: Estimation Theory and Volume II: Detection Theory are excellent to start with IMHO.

Melsa and Cohn Decision and Estimation Theory
Might be worth $10.

Thank you — I ordered it

As mateC suggested above Steven Kay's Statistical Signal Processing Volume I: Estimation Theory & Statistical Signal Processing Volume I: Detection Theory are great starting points. Both books are organized extremely well with good in text examples. The end of each book then has good summary chapters outlining when to use each specific method and extensions to complex numbers. Dr. Kay always provides the reader with additional references if more detail is desired.
